# Dimensionless Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, dimensional-analysis

I have a question about the dimensionless Schrodinger equation. When solving a problem of quantum tunneling of electrons through potential barrier, for example we can use units $\hbar=m_e=1$. After finding solution and calculating some physical quantities, one should reconvert everything back to physical units. How to do that? I need the proof. For example, what is the unit of length in this units $\hbar=m_e=1$?

Comment: I believe this particular choice of units are called Hartree units, you can find a little more information about them here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units, and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_atomic_units.

Comment: Yes, as Phillip correctly pointed out, you are thinking of Hartree units. If you are using your physical constants in Hartree units, your results will be in Hartree units as well, so lengths in bohr for example, and energies in hartree. You can easily convert them to any other scale as you would normally convert units. Note please that this is not the same as being 'dimensionless', as you still have dimensions, just not SI.